# Spring Data partial upsert not persisiting type information

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data with MongoDB to store very dynamic config data in a toolkit. These `Config` objects consist of a few organizational fields, along with a `data` field of type `Object`. On some instances of `Config`, the `data` object refers to a more deeply nested subdocument (such as `"data.foo.bar"` within the database. – this field name is set by `getDataField()` below). These `Config` objects are manipulated as they're sent to the database, so the storage code looks something like this:

```
MongoTemplate template; // This is autowired into the class.
Query query; // This is the same query which (successfully) finds the object.
Config myConfig; // The config to create or update in Mongo

Update update = new Update()
    .set(getDataField(), myConfig.getData())
    .set(UPDATE_TIME_FIELD, new Date())
    .setOnInsert(CREATE_TIME_FIELD, new Date())
    .setOnInsert(NAME_FIELD, myConfig.getName());

template.upsert(query, update, Config.class);
```

Spring recursively converts the `data` object into a `DBObject` correctly, but neither the data document nor any of its subdocuments have `"_class"` fields in the database. Consequentially, they do not deserialize correctly.

These issues seem quite similar to those previously reported in [DATAMONGO-392](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-392) , [DATAMONGO-407](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-407), and DATAMONGO-724. Those, however, have all been fixed. (I am using spring-data-mongodb 1.4.2.RELEASE)

Am I doing something incorrectly? Is there a possibility that this is a Spring issue?

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful if you describe, what's actually going wrong. What does "not deserialize correctly" mean?

Comment: Because the data field has no "_class" field, and is mapped to a java field of type Object, The mapper can't infer what type the data object was originally deserialized from. It defaults to a Map<String, Object>, which obviously can't be used as the original type.

I have actually found a workaround (converting the data field to a DBObject before setting it in the upsert), so this is no longer super critical to me. If you're concerned that it could be a legitimate Spring issue, I'd be happy to continue to provide information.

Thanks for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Came across a similar issue. One solution is to write your own Converter for Config.class.